# Having multiple reduce tasks assemble a single HDFS file as output

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there any low level API in Hadoop allowing multiple reduce tasks running on different machines to assemble a single HDFS as output of their computation?

Something like, a stub HDFS file is created at the beginning of the job then each reducer creates, as output, a variable number of data blocks and assigns them to this file according to a certain order

Comment: Do you need single merged output file on HDFS or on local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, that would be an unnecessary complication for a rare use case.

What you should do

**option 1**  - add some code at the end of your hadoop command

```
int result = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

if (result == 0) { // status code OK
    // ls job output directory, collect part-r-XXXXX file names
    // create HDFS readers for files
    // merge them in a single file in whatever way you want
}
```

All of the required methods are present in hadoop FileSystem api.

**option 2** - add job to merge files

You can create a generic hadoop job that would accept directory name as input and pass everything as-is to the single reducer, that would merge results into one output file. Call this job in a pipeline with your main job.

This would work faster for big inputs.

Comment: I am aware that it would be a rare use case. Nevertheless, I was hoping for some low-level arcane solutions to exist. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want merged output file on local, you can use hadoop command getmerge to combine multiple reduce task files into one single local output file, below is command for same.

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /output/dir/on/hdfs/ /desired/local/output/file.txt
```